# How to check internet connectivity in android?

Tags: android

friends,

i am trying to check internetconnectivity in android and using following code

```
final ConnectivityManager conn_manager = (ConnectivityManager) 
            this.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);


            final NetworkInfo network_info = conn_manager.getActiveNetworkInfo();
            if ( network_info != null && network_info.isConnected() ) 
            {
                return true;
            }
            else
            {
                return false;
            }
```

but it gives me network/ wifi connectivity if wifi is connected it gives me true and if internet is not connected then it also gives me true.

any one guide me what is the solution?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Probably some issue with the logic you have in the `if` clause there.

I use this:

```
/**
 * Checks if we have a valid Internet Connection on the device.
 * @param ctx
 * @return True if device has internet
 *
 * Code from: http://www.androidsnippets.org/snippets/131/
 */
public static boolean haveInternet(Context ctx) {

    NetworkInfo info = (NetworkInfo) ((ConnectivityManager) ctx
            .getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE)).getActiveNetworkInfo();

    if (info == null || !info.isConnected()) {
        return false;
    }
    if (info.isRoaming()) {
        // here is the roaming option you can change it if you want to
        // disable internet while roaming, just return false
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: How is it possible to extend this code to check Internet Connectivity in time intervals?

Comment: Probably a bad idea to monitor in time intervals, instead you should subscribe to the connectivity broadcast and action on it. See this related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3307237/how-can-i-monitor-the-network-connection-status-in-android/3307565#3307565

Comment: I tried using this, but on a 2.1 device it reported false when connected to wifi mode while in airplane mode.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [requstRouteToHost](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/ConnectivityManager.html#requestRouteToHost%28int,%20int%29) to check if you can connect to a specific IP address.

Answer (score 0):

Use this nifty library: http://code.google.com/p/connectivity

You can subscribe to network status notification and get a callback when network status changes. Or, you can query directly if network is available. Very simple to use.