# how to check wifi or 3g network is available on android device

Tags: java, android

Here, my android device supports both wifi and 3g. At particular time which network is available on this device. Because my requirement is when 3g is available I have to upload small amount of data. when wifi is available entire data have to upload. So, I have to check connection is wifi or 3g. Please help me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Take a look at that http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2789612/how-can-i-check-whether-an-android-device-is-connected-to-the-web http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3119607/how-to-be-notified-on-wifi-network-status-change http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3211978/how-to-check-internet-connectivity-in-android http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2919414/get-network-type http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=ConnectivityManager

Comment: @govardhan: +1 I am also have this problem. did you get any answer for it?

Comment: This link contains the code you need http://stackoverflow.com/a/9256972/191246.

Answer (score 53):

I use this:

```
/**
 * Checks if we have a valid Internet Connection on the device.
 * @param ctx
 * @return True if device has internet
 *
 * Code from: http://www.androidsnippets.org/snippets/131/
 */
public static boolean haveInternet(Context ctx) {

    NetworkInfo info = (NetworkInfo) ((ConnectivityManager) ctx
            .getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE)).getActiveNetworkInfo();

    if (info == null || !info.isConnected()) {
        return false;
    }
    if (info.isRoaming()) {
        // here is the roaming option you can change it if you want to
        // disable internet while roaming, just return false
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

You also need

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
```

in AndroidMainfest.xml

**To get the network type you can use this code snippet:**

```
ConnectivityManager conMan = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);

//mobile
State mobile = conMan.getNetworkInfo(0).getState();

//wifi
State wifi = conMan.getNetworkInfo(1).getState();
```

and then use it like that:

```
if (mobile == NetworkInfo.State.CONNECTED || mobile == NetworkInfo.State.CONNECTING) {
    //mobile
} else if (wifi == NetworkInfo.State.CONNECTED || wifi == NetworkInfo.State.CONNECTING) {
    //wifi
}
```

To get the type of the mobile network I would try [TelephonyManager#getNetworkType](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/TelephonyManager.html#getNetworkType()) or [NetworkInfo#getSubtypeName](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/NetworkInfo.html#getSubtypeName())

Comment: This code gives me error when I use this on a tablet without sim.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add below permission in android manifest file:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
```

After that you can use below functions to check wifi or mobile network is connected or not

```
public static boolean isWifiConnected(Context context) {
        ConnectivityManager connManager = (ConnectivityManager) context
                .getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        NetworkInfo netInfo = connManager.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI);
        return ((netInfo != null) && netInfo.isConnected());
    }

public static boolean isMobileConnected(Context context) {
        ConnectivityManager connManager = (ConnectivityManager) context
                .getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        NetworkInfo netInfo = connManager.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_MOBILE);
        return ((netInfo != null) && netInfo.isConnected());
    }
```

Some references from developer.android.com are:

1. https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/ConnectivityManager.html
2. https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/NetworkInfo.html
3. https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/ConnectivityManager.html#getActiveNetworkInfo()

Answer (score 0):

First get a reference to the ConnectivityManager and then [check the Wifi and 3G status](http://d.android.com/reference/android/net/NetworkInfo.html) of the device.
You'll need the ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE permission to use this service.

```
    ConnectivityManager connManager = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    NetworkInfo mWifi = connManager.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI);
    NetworkInfo mMobile = connManager.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_MOBILE);

    if (mWifi.isAvailable() == true) {
        return "Connected to WiFi";
    } else if (mMobile.isAvailable() == true) {
        return "Connected to Mobile Network";
    } else return "No internet Connection"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this method to check whether your internet connection is **2G, 3G or 4G**:

```
public String getNetworkClass(Context context) {
    TelephonyManager mTelephonyManager = (TelephonyManager)
        context.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
    int networkType = mTelephonyManager.getNetworkType();
    switch (networkType) {
        case TelephonyManager.NETWORK_TYPE_GPRS:
        case TelephonyManager.NETWORK_TYPE_EDGE:
        case TelephonyManager.NETWORK_TYPE_CDMA:
        case TelephonyManager.NETWORK_TYPE_1xRTT:
        case TelephonyManager.NETWORK_TYPE_IDEN:
            return "2G";
        case TelephonyManager.NETWORK_TYPE_UMTS:
        case TelephonyManager.NETWORK_TYPE_EVDO_0:
        case TelephonyManager.NETWORK_TYPE_EVDO_A:
        case TelephonyManager.NETWORK_TYPE_HSDPA:
        case TelephonyManager.NETWORK_TYPE_HSUPA:
        case TelephonyManager.NETWORK_TYPE_HSPA:
        case TelephonyManager.NETWORK_TYPE_EVDO_B:
        case TelephonyManager.NETWORK_TYPE_EHRPD:
        case TelephonyManager.NETWORK_TYPE_HSPAP:
            return "3G";
        case TelephonyManager.NETWORK_TYPE_LTE:
            return "4G";
        default:
            return "Unknown";
    }
}
```

And using following method you can check if **internet is available or not**, and get whether you are accessing the internet via a **mobile network or WiFi**:

```
public String getNetworkType(Context context){
    String networkType = null;
    ConnectivityManager connectivityManager = (ConnectivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    NetworkInfo activeNetwork = connectivityManager.getActiveNetworkInfo();
    if (activeNetwork != null) { // connected to the internet
        if (activeNetwork.getType() == ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI) {
                networkType = "WiFi";
        } else if (activeNetwork.getType() == ConnectivityManager.TYPE_MOBILE) {
            networkType = "Mobile";
        }
    } else {
        // not connected to the internet
    }
    return networkType;
}
```