# how continuously know wifi or data plan is enabled or disabled in android

Tags: android, wifi

In my android app based on connection type (wifi, data plan and one more option) I am displaying an icon on the screen.

I am able to get whether wifi is enabled or not, but I don't know how to get info on whether the data plan is enabled or not. How do I do this?

I need to  know continuously whether wifi is enabled or data plan is enabled. If wifi is enabled after some time it may disconnect, in which case I need check whether the data plan is enabled or not. Based on the connection type I need to change icon on one of my screen in my app.

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to check wifi or 3g network is available on android device](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3262781/how-to-check-wifi-or-3g-network-is-available-on-android-device)

Answer (score 0):

Try listening to CONNECTIVITY_ACTION

Take a look at these questions for more details:

[Network listener Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1783117/network-listener-android)

[How can I monitor the network connection status in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3307237/how-can-i-monitor-the-network-connection-status-in-android)