# Android - How to know if device is WiFi only?

Tags: android, android-wifi

Is there anyway we can check if the Android Device is WiFi only? For example Nexus 7 have WiFi-Only device and WiFi&3G device.

Comment: You mean, want to check wifi connection on your device??

Comment: You mean you want to check whether its wifi enabled or not?

Comment: or do you want to check if your devices doesn't have 3/4G network enable?

Comment: I want to know if the device can only have WIFI. Not if the device connected to WIFI. For example the Nexus 7 have Wifi-only & wifi/3G.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to check that the wifi is connected or not then see this question:
[How do I see if Wi-Fi is connected on Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3841317/how-to-see-if-wifi-is-connected-in-android)

If you want to check the network type than see this question:
[how to check wifi or 3g network is available on android device](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3262781/how-to-check-wifi-or-3g-network-is-available-on-android-device)