# How can I monitor the network connection status in Android?

Tags: android, networking

I have a Service that is downloading a file from a server. I warn the user to only download the file over Wireless LAN before the download starts.

My problem is that my download gets stuck if I loose the network connection. Is there a way to listen for changes in network connection or if it is lost entirely?

Answer (score 80, accepted):

Listen for [CONNECTIVITY_ACTION](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/ConnectivityManager.html#CONNECTIVITY_ACTION)

This looks like good [sample code](http://www.netmite.com/android/mydroid/frameworks/base/core/java/android/net/NetworkConnectivityListener.java).  Here is a snippet:

```
BroadcastReceiver networkStateReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Log.w("Network Listener", "Network Type Changed");
    }
};

IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(ConnectivityManager.CONNECTIVITY_ACTION);        
registerReceiver(networkStateReceiver, filter);
```

Comment: I added a anonymous broadcast receiver just to make the sample totally clear. Thanks for the answer.

Comment: What can I do with that networkStateReceiver, and filter objects ??? Please show more detials....!

Comment: Don't forget to unregister the receiver when the activity/fragment destroys/pauses

Comment: Be careful with the concurrency in the example: even though `startListening()` and `stopListnening()` method are synchronized on their own, **not synchronized to each other**. If two threads are calling the functions independently then there could be a race condition. You need to add a lock object and synchronize to that from both methods.