# Android: Update the Widget on Network Connection Availability

Tags: android, android-widget, android-networking

> Hi Friends,
>
> I have an Home screen Widget, which is
>   invoking the webservice and display
>   some content. Now the issue is
>   whenever the Device loses the
>   Connection I need to update the widget
>   with the message "No connection" and
>   whenever the device regains the
>   connection I have to again update the
>   widget by calling the webservice. Any
>   Ideas please do share.
>
> Thanks in advance
>
> The following Link also provides good
>   solution:

[How can I monitor the network connection status in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3307237/how-can-i-monitor-the-network-connection-status-in-android)