# Progress dialog in Android

Tags: android, progressdialog

I am fully aware on how to display progress dialogues in my application. I just want to know if there is anyway that we can set a "timeout" interval for this progress dialog. [I mean is there any API for this]

I can always run a thread for this, but thought it would be better if there was an inbuilt API already..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no built-in api. Just use AsyncTask or thread, how you have already mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a Handler as well (post a delayed message to the handler and the handler will close the dialog). I don't know any way to tell the dialog to close itself after a given time.

```
private ProgressDialog dialog;
private Handler closeHandler = new Handler() {
  public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
    if (dialog!=null) dialog.dismiss();
  }
};


public void openDialog() {
  // Open the dialog

  // Close it after 2 seconds
  closeHandler.sendEmptyMessageDelayed(0, 2000);
}
```

Comment: I am currently using the handler way to do that. It is a progress dialog for downloading some content from internet. What happens here is if in the middle of the downloading process, the internet connectivity goes away, the progress dialog keeps repeating forever. This is because I have called the dismiss method only after the download is complete.

Comment: You should set a timeout on your Http request as well else, you will be keeping a download in progress during the whole life of your activity. IMHO you are solving the problem with the wrong solution.

Comment: Then listen for network connection and if connectivity goes , dismiss the dialog and any web operations. check   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3307237/how-can-i-monitor-the-network-connection-status-in-android

Comment: Ain't any exception thrown when connection goes down?