# how to check the internet connectivity in application

Tags: android

i developing the project that is uses the internet my problem is that check the application is connected to internet or not
i used the fallowing code but error is generated

```
public void onClick(View v)
{
    ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    NetworkInfo info= cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
    boolean a= cm.getActiveNetworkInfo().isConnectedOrConnecting();
    if(a==true){
        Toast("Connected");
    }
    else{
        Toast("Not Connected");
    }
}
```

Comment: What error? please add it to you question

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Please try below function . If internet connection is available in device then it will return true otherwise it will return false.

```
public static boolean CheckInternet(Context context) 
{
    ConnectivityManager connec = (ConnectivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    android.net.NetworkInfo wifi = connec.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI);
    android.net.NetworkInfo mobile = connec.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_MOBILE);

    if (wifi.isConnected()) {
        return true;
    } else if (mobile.isConnected()) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Add Permission in android manifest file.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this in AndroidManifest file , if you haven't done it yet.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
```

check here,
[How can I monitor the network connection status in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3307237/how-can-i-monitor-the-network-connection-status-in-android)

Answer (score 0):

```
try {
ConnectivityManager conMgr = (ConnectivityManager)getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE); 
NetworkInfo info= conMgr.getActiveNetworkInfo(); 

    if(info != null && info.isConnected()) 
    {
        //Internet is there
    }
    else{
        //Internet is not there
    }
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
```

hope it will help you...