# How can I listen for network connectivity in android

Tags: android

Can you please tell me how can I detect  network connectivity in android?

An example is when the airplane mode is on and off. How can I listen for that?

Thank you.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I monitor the network connection status in Android?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3307237/how-can-i-monitor-the-network-connection-status-in-android)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Can you please tell me how can I detect network connectivity in android?

This has been asked and answered. See this [stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1560788/how-to-check-internet-access-on-android-inetaddress-never-timeouts) for details.

---

> An example is when the airplane mode is on and off. How can I listen for that?

The [ACTION_AIRPLANE_MODE_CHANGED](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_AIRPLANE_MODE_CHANGED) is broadcast when ever the airplane mode changes.

Answer (score 10):

Kurtis link describes numerous ways of checking the current network state.

To listen for the network *change events*, your activity must register the broadcast receiver that listens for the CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    registerReceiver(new BroadcastReceiver() {      
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            Log.i(TAG, "Hey, net?");
        }}, new IntentFilter("android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE"));
}
```

You also need to declare your intent filter in the manifest:

```
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE"/>
        </intent-filter>
```

and also add android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE permission.