# Android ContentProvider check network access

Tags: android, android-contentprovider

is there any way how to take advantage of ContentProvider to check, whether my Android phone is connected to the internet?

Thanks

Comment: how this is possible using ContentProvider ?  This is possible using ConnectivityManager  & NetworkInfo ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
// check internet connectivity
public static boolean isNetworkAvailable(Context context) {

    boolean networkStatus;
    try {
        ConnectivityManager connectivityManager = (ConnectivityManager) context
            .getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        NetworkInfo activeNetworkInfo = connectivityManager
            .getActiveNetworkInfo();

        networkStatus = (activeNetworkInfo != null && activeNetworkInfo.isConnected()) ? true : false;

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        DinotaLogger.log(e, Level.SEVERE);
        networkStatus = false;
    }

    return networkStatus;
}
```

Please make sure to put in manifest file. If you are using an emulator to check this, press `F8` to disable network access. This works fine with android 2.3.3 emulator.

Answer (score 2):

I think you want [ConnectivityManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/ConnectivityManager.html).  There's an example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3307565/931277).

That explains how to register for notifications.  To check directly, you can get a ConnectivityManager instance:

```
ConnectivityManager mgr = (ConnectivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
NetworkInfo info = mgr.getActiveNetworkInfo();
boolean is_connected = info.isConnected();
boolean is_available = info.isAvailable();
```

Comment: That's probably my preferred way to test for network connectivity. You can keep polling for network connectivity before each call to a web service, and the NetworkInfo.isConnectingOrConnected() method can be quite useful.

Answer (score 1):

this code should help you to query if the data network is available or not:

```
   public static boolean isDataNetworkAvailable(Context context){
        try{
            ConnectivityManager connectivityManager = (ConnectivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
            NetworkInfo activeNetworkInfo = connectivityManager.getActiveNetworkInfo();
            return activeNetworkInfo != null;
        }
        catch (Exception e) { return false; }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

It will tell you in boolean that your android is connected to internet.

I used that:

```
public boolean isNetworkAvailable() {
            try{
                Context context = getApplicationContext();
                ConnectivityManager connectivity = (ConnectivityManager) 
                context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
                if (connectivity == null) {

                }else{
                    NetworkInfo[] info = connectivity.getAllNetworkInfo();
                    if (info != null) {
                        for (int i = 0; i < info.length; i++) {
                            if (info[i].getState() == NetworkInfo.State.CONNECTED) {
                                return true;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }catch (Exception e) {
                System.out.println("error");
            }
            return false;
        }
```

Also put:

```
<uses-permission> android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
```

this line to your android manifest.

I Used this in my application.