# Broadcast receiver to monitor internet connectivity not working

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

I'm trying to make broadcast receiver that listen to internet connectivity and then do some tasks when connected.

I do not receive any notification when I disable or enable my WIFI on my real device or disable/enable the data access in emulator. the action CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE is no longer supported.

```
  public class InternetConnectivityReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
Context context;
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    this.context = context;

    Log.i(TAG, "Internet Conenction State Changed");
}
}
```

Manifest

```
 <application
    android:icon="@android:drawable/arrow_down_float"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >



      <receiver android:name=".InternetConnectivityReceiver">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.net.conn.BACKGROUND_DATA_SETTING_CHANGED">

                </action>
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
......
</application>
```

Comment: possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3307237/how-can-i-monitor-the-network-connection-status-in-android

Comment: have you given internet permissions ?

Comment: Yes, permissions are given. I tried to register dynamically on code and it's working but when activity finished, it does not listen any more. That means in general that the permissions are fine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Developer documentation for `ConnectivityManager`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/ConnectivityManager.html) says:

> **BACKGROUND_DATA_SETTING_CHANGED**
>
> This constant is deprecated. As of ICE_CREAM_SANDWICH, availability of
>   background data depends on several combined factors, and this
>   broadcast is no longer sent.

Try listening for `"android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE"` instead.

Comment: Oh, I think I get it wrong or it was written wrong some where. I thought android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE is the one whic was deprecated as also I can't find it in the auto complete. Thanks so much, this worked.