# prvevent Application from Crashing

Tags: android

```
private void sendPostRequest(String lo, String la, String username,
            String batlevel) {

        class SendPostReqAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

            @Override
            protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

                String lo = params[0];
                String la = params[1];
                String username = params[2];
                String b_level = params[3];

                System.out.println("*** doInBackground ** paramUsername " + lo
                        + " paramPassword :" + la + "Username" + username
                        + "BatLevel" + b_level);

                HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();

                // In a POST request, we don't pass the values in the URL.
                // Therefore we use only the web page URL as the parameter of
                // the HttpPost argument
                HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(
                        "http://gateway.ceylonlinux.com/Ceylon_Steel/service/markGPSLocation");



                BasicNameValuePair longtiude = new BasicNameValuePair(
                        "latitude", lo);
                BasicNameValuePair lattiude = new BasicNameValuePair(
                        "longitude", la);
                BasicNameValuePair username_param = new BasicNameValuePair(
                        "userName", username);
                BasicNameValuePair batery_level = new BasicNameValuePair(
                        "batteryLevel", b_level);

                // We add the content that we want to pass with the POST request
                // to as name-value pairs
                // Now we put those sending details to an ArrayList with type
                // safe of NameValuePair
                List<BasicNameValuePair> nameValuePairList = new ArrayList();
                nameValuePairList.add(longtiude);
                nameValuePairList.add(lattiude);
                nameValuePairList.add(username_param);
                nameValuePairList.add(batery_level);

                try {
                    // UrlEncodedFormEntity is an entity composed of a list of
                    // url-encoded pairs.
                    // This is typically useful while sending an HTTP POST
                    // request.
                    UrlEncodedFormEntity urlEncodedFormEntity = new UrlEncodedFormEntity(
                            nameValuePairList);

                    // setEntity() hands the entity (here it is
                    // urlEncodedFormEntity) to the request.
                    httpPost.setEntity(urlEncodedFormEntity);

                    try {
                        // HttpResponse is an interface just like HttpPost.
                        // Therefore we can't initialize them
                        HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient
                                .execute(httpPost);

                        // According to the JAVA API, InputStream constructor do
                        // nothing.
                        // So we can't initialize InputStream although it is not
                        // an interface
                        InputStream inputStream = httpResponse.getEntity()
                                .getContent();

                        InputStreamReader inputStreamReader = new InputStreamReader(
                                inputStream);

                        BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(
                                inputStreamReader);

                        StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();

                        String bufferedStrChunk = null;

                        while ((bufferedStrChunk = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
                            stringBuilder.append(bufferedStrChunk);
                        }

                        return stringBuilder.toString();

                    } catch (ClientProtocolException cpe) {
                        System.out
                                .println("First Exception caz of HttpResponese :"
                                        + cpe);
                        cpe.printStackTrace();
                    } catch (IOException ioe) {
                        System.out
                                .println("Second Exception caz of HttpResponse :"
                                        + ioe);
                        ioe.printStackTrace();
                    }

                } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException uee) {
                    System.out
                            .println("An Exception given because of UrlEncodedFormEntity argument :"
                                    + uee);
                    uee.printStackTrace();
                }

                return null;
            }

            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
                super.onPostExecute(result);

                // Log.i("Result", result);

            }
        }

        SendPostReqAsyncTask sendPostReqAsyncTask = new SendPostReqAsyncTask();
        sendPostReqAsyncTask.execute(lo, la, username, batlevel);
    }
```

Here I write Above Code to send some Data to Server within a Android Background Service .It 
Works Fine .But when i witched off the internet the Application will be crashed.All iwant to do is to prevent application from Crashing when the internet is Not Available.

```
01-02 11:46:57.437: I/System.out(10409): Second Exception caz of HttpResponse :org.apache.http.conn.HttpHostConnectException: Connection to http://192.168.1.1:3128 refused
01-02 11:46:57.445: W/System.err(10409): org.apache.http.conn.HttpHostConnectException: Connection to http://192.168.1.1:3128 refused
01-02 11:46:57.476: W/System.err(10409):    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:183)
01-02 11:46:57.484: W/System.err(10409):    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPoolEntry.open(AbstractPoolEntry.java:164)
01-02 11:46:57.492: W/System.err(10409):    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPooledConnAdapter.open(AbstractPooledConnAdapter.java:119)
01-02 11:46:57.492: W/System.err(10409):    at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:360)
01-02 11:46:57.492: W/System.err(10409):    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:555)
01-02 11:46:57.492: W/System.err(10409):    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:487)
01-02 11:46:57.515: W/System.err(10409):    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:465)
01-02 11:46:57.523: W/System.err(10409):    at org.apache.cordova.example.MyService$1SendPostReqAsyncTask.doInBackground(MyService.java:253)
01-02 11:46:57.523: W/System.err(10409):    at org.apache.cordova.example.MyService$1SendPostReqAsyncTask.doInBackground(MyService.java:1)
01-02 11:46:57.539: W/System.err(10409):    at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
01-02 11:46:57.539: W/System.err(10409):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:305)
01-02 11:46:57.539: W/System.err(10409):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:137)
01-02 11:46:57.546: W/System.err(10409):    at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:230)
01-02 11:46:57.546: W/System.err(10409):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1076)
01-02 11:46:57.562: W/System.err(10409):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:569)
01-02 11:46:57.679: W/System.err(10409):    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
01-02 11:46:57.703: W/System.err(10409): Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: failed to connect to /192.168.1.1 (port 3128): connect failed: ETIMEDOUT (Connection timed out)
01-02 11:46:57.734: W/System.err(10409):    at libcore.io.IoBridge.connect(IoBridge.java:114)
01-02 11:46:57.796: W/System.err(10409):    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:192)
01-02 11:46:57.828: W/System.err(10409):    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:459)
01-02 11:46:57.875: W/System.err(10409):    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:842)
01-02 11:46:57.875: W/System.err(10409):    at org.apache.http.conn.scheme.PlainSocketFactory.connectSocket(PlainSocketFactory.java:119)
01-02 11:46:57.890: W/System.err(10409):    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:144)
01-02 11:46:57.953: W/System.err(10409):    ... 15 more
01-02 11:46:57.953: W/System.err(10409): Caused by: libcore.io.ErrnoException: connect failed: ETIMEDOUT (Connection timed out)
01-02 11:46:58.023: W/System.err(10409):    at libcore.io.Posix.connect(Native Method)
01-02 11:46:58.031: W/System.err(10409):    at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.connect(BlockGuardOs.java:85)
01-02 11:46:58.031: W/System.err(10409):    at libcore.io.IoBridge.connectErrno(IoBridge.java:127)
01-02 11:46:58.039: W/System.err(10409):    at libcore.io.IoBridge.connect(IoBridge.java:112)
01-02 11:46:58.039: W/System.err(10409):    ... 20 more
01-02 11:46:58.039: D/AndroidRuntime(10409): Shutting down VM
01-02 11:46:58.039: W/dalvikvm(10409): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40f092a0)
01-02 11:46:58.062: E/AndroidRuntime(10409): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-02 11:46:58.062: E/AndroidRuntime(10409): java.lang.NullPointerException: println needs a message
01-02 11:46:58.062: E/AndroidRuntime(10409):    at android.util.Log.println_native(Native Method)
01-02 11:46:58.062: E/AndroidRuntime(10409):    at android.util.Log.i(Log.java:190)
01-02 11:46:58.062: E/AndroidRuntime(10409):    at org.apache.cordova.example.MyService$1SendPostReqAsyncTask.onPostExecute(MyService.java:304)
01-02 11:46:58.062: E/AndroidRuntime(10409):    at org.apache.cordova.example.MyService$1SendPostReqAsyncTask.onPostExecute(MyService.java:1)
01-02 11:46:58.062: E/AndroidRuntime(10409):    at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:631)
01-02 11:46:58.062: E/AndroidRuntime(10409):    at android.os.AsyncTask.access$600(AsyncTask.java:177)
01-02 11:46:58.062: E/AndroidRuntime(10409):    at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:644)
```

Comment: Post your logcat error.

Comment: 01-02 11:46:57.437: I/System.out(10409): Second Exception caz of HttpResponse :org.apache.http.conn.HttpHostConnectException: Connection to http://192.168.1.1:3128 refused

Comment: check device internet connection before your task...

Comment: Please Post your complete log cat error

Comment: @user2889058 Check out my answer it might help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try out by checking the internet connection using the below method:

```
 public boolean isConnectingToInternet(){
        ConnectivityManager connectivity = (ConnectivityManager) _context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
          if (connectivity != null) 
          {
              NetworkInfo[] info = connectivity.getAllNetworkInfo();
              if (info != null) 
                  for (int i = 0; i < info.length; i++) 
                      if (info[i].getState() == NetworkInfo.State.CONNECTED)
                      {
                          return true;
                      }

          }
          return false;
    }
```

Also provide internet permission and network permission in your manifest file

```
 <!-- Internet Permissions -->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

<!-- Network State Permissions -->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
```

Use the above method as below:

```
 if(isConnectingToInternet())
 {
  SendPostReqAsyncTask sendPostReqAsyncTask = new SendPostReqAsyncTask();
   sendPostReqAsyncTask.execute(lo, la, username, batlevel);
 }
else{
             //Show alert to user for internet connection not available.
    }
```

Make sure you are passing the parameters in your `SendPostReqAsyncTask` method using the `params[]` array.

```
            String lo = params[0];
            String la = params[1];
            String username = params[2];
            String b_level = params[3];
```

Does the above strings gets the Values ? Try to print the values.

Answer (score 2):

Before starting the `AsyncTask` ,check whether the device is enabled with Network connections or not

```
private boolean isNetworkAvailable() {
    ConnectivityManager connectivityManager = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    NetworkInfo activeNetworkInfo = connectivityManager
            .getActiveNetworkInfo();
    return activeNetworkInfo != null && activeNetworkInfo.isConnected();
}
```

**Note** Dont forgot to add the permission in the manifest file

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
```

Answer (score 1):

Please check for internet connectivity and also give internet connectivity permission

Comment: Please check for internet connectivity and also give internet connectivity permission  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

Answer (score 0):

Check before starting the network operations.But this code only checks when you start your application.

```
    WifiManager wifi = (WifiManager)getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
      if (wifi.isWifiEnabled()){
     //wifi is enabled
      sendPostRequest(lo,la,username,batlevel);
         }
       else
       {
      Toast.makeText(context,"Please turn on the wifi...",5000);
          }
```

If your wifi is turned on before starting your app this might worked for you.But if user turned off the wifi while you are sending/receiving data from server it might again crash.
So i think you have to constantly check the wifi access.Please check this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14839576/constantly-check-for-wireless-network-change) to solve this problem also.

Permission you need

```
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
  <user-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
```