# Background service to detect network status in Xamarin.Android

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android, xamarin-studio

I am developing Xamarin.Android app.
In my app , I want to implement a background service  , which will run indefinitely to detect changes in network status.
i.e. if network connection goes off , it should send such notification .
It should send notification too when network connection becomes on(device got a network connection).
Can anyone tell me how to implement such service in Xamarin.Android ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How much reasearch did you do?

Have a look on the ConnectivityManager:
http://developer.xamarin.com/recipes/android/networking/networkinfo/detect_network_connection/

You could make a listener yourself, which fires an event when it changes?

[Network listener Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1783117/network-listener-android) and
[How can I monitor the network connection status in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3307237/how-can-i-monitor-the-network-connection-status-in-android)

Comment: Thank you @Casper Skoubo , your links are worked for me.Thanks a lot !!

Comment: @Suraj is this working in closed app too? Or only suppended app?

Answer (score 3):

Create object of following class by passing `Activity` context. Your application network handled this class.

```
public class NetworkReachability
{
    Activity activity;
    Thread checkNetworkActiveThread;
    String conectedVia;
    ConnectivityManager connectivityManager;
    bool isDialogShowing;
    AlertDialog.Builder builder;

    public NetworkReachability (Activity activity)
    {
        this.activity = activity;
        connectivityManager = (ConnectivityManager)activity.GetSystemService (Context.ConnectivityService);
        this.doAlertDialog ();
        this.CheckNetworkRechability ();
    }

    private void CheckNetworkRechability ()
    {
        checkNetworkActiveThread = new Thread (new ThreadStart (CheckNetworkAvailable));
        checkNetworkActiveThread.Start ();
    }

    private async void CheckNetworkAvailable ()
    {
        bool isNetwork = await Task.Run (() => this.NetworkRechableOrNot ());

        if (!isNetwork) {

            activity.RunOnUiThread (() => {
                try {

                    if (!isDialogShowing) {

                        isDialogShowing = true;
                        builder.Show ();
                    }
                } catch (Exception ex) {

                    Console.WriteLine ("NetworkReachability -> CheckNetworkRechability:" + ex.Message);
                }
            });


        } else {
            isDialogShowing = false;
            this.CheckNetworkAvailable ();
        }
    }

    private bool NetworkRechableOrNot ()
    {

        var activeConnection = connectivityManager.ActiveNetworkInfo;
        if ((activeConnection != null) && activeConnection.IsConnected) {
            // we are connected to a network.
            if (activeConnection.Type.ToString ().ToUpper ().Equals ("WIFI")) {
                return true;
            } else
                return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }

    private void doAlertDialog ()
    {
        if (builder != null)
            builder.Dispose ();

        builder = new AlertDialog.Builder (activity);
        builder.SetTitle ("Network not reachable");
        builder.SetMessage ("Plz check network");
        builder.SetCancelable (true);
        builder.SetNegativeButton ("Retry", AlertRetryClick);
        builder.SetPositiveButton ("Cancel", AlertCancelClick);
    }

    private void AlertRetryClick (object sender1, DialogClickEventArgs args)
    {
        isDialogShowing = false;
        this.CheckNetworkAvailable ();
    }

    private void AlertCancelClick (object sender1, DialogClickEventArgs args)
    {
        isDialogShowing = false;
        Intent intent = new Intent(activity.Application.ApplicationContext, typeof(SplashActivity));
        intent.AddFlags ( ActivityFlags.ClearTop | ActivityFlags.NewTask | ActivityFlags.ClearTask);
        intent.PutExtra (Constant.EXIT, Constant.EXIT);
        activity.StartActivity(intent);
        activity.Finish ();
    }
}
```