# how to check internet connection and update details in android programmatically?

Tags: android

I would like to know if there is any way to disable mobile data connection in android programmatically. Since there is a class known as WifiManager to handle the wifi

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to check internet connectivity in android?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3211978/how-to-check-internet-connectivity-in-android)

Comment: please check this link http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/ConnectivityManager.html

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11555366/enable-disable-data-connection-in-android-programmatically

Answer (score 0):

No reliable way using Android APIs. You can't enable/disable mobile data programmatically unless you use OEM provided APIs.